# How do I configure pip inside a virtualenv to install packages to the current directory root?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm using the serverless framework with AWS Lambda. When using pip.conf with `pip3.6`, I'd like to set the "target-dir" to the 'current directory'.

Setting it to "." like so:

```
[global]
target = "."
```

doesn't work, because pip creates a new directory called "`.`" in my `virtualenv` root, and proceeds to install stuff in there. I've tried without the quotes. I had also tried `./`, but this creates a directory called `."`.

I'm using `virtualenv` (via `venv` with `python3.6`), but I need the packages to live in the root directory of the virtualenv when I install with pip, because of AWS Lambda's limitations.

Comment: Why do you think AWS Lambda limitations require the packages to be deployed in the root directory? I add the following to the top of my Python Lambda functions to load dependencies from the default `lib` directory: `sys.path.append('./lib')`

Comment: I did not know of this, so thank you @MarkB! However, the [Lambda docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) specifically mention to make a `.zip` file with the dependencies in the `root` of the project (point (2) at the bottom of the page). Are there any gotchas with the method you've proposed which is why it's not in the docs?

Answer (score -1):

[Edited]
`pip.conf` is actually a [standard INI file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/?highlight=pip.conf#config-file), so it allows only for **absolute** paths (-> absolute, yet it takes as root the lambda function's root); moreover it cannot use variables internally.

### Method 1

Therefore, you should include the full path (starting from root, '/') in the `target=` option.

In order to do so, you can try to retrieve the current directory in AWS Lambda with (or something similar):

```
lambdash pwd
```

I.e., try to get a shell and invoke *pwd* (= print working directory). Use this information to fill in the right path to the `target` var.

### Method 2

However a INI file can be created/changed programmatically.

Thus, you can create your project as a distributable one (like one for pypi or other DVCS) and set up a `setup.py`

A tutorial to ready your project for distribution can be found [here](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The specific discussion on the *setup.py* can be found [here](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html#creating-the-scaffolding)

A function that can be added to your `setup.py` can be as follows (adapt freely):

```
# remember to add the imports:
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install
import ConfigParser
import io

class CustomInstallCommand(install):
    """Customized setuptools install command."""
    def run(self):
        config= ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
        config.read(r'pip.conf')
        config.set('target', os.environ['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'])
        with open(r'pip.conf', 'wb') as configfile:
            config.write(configfile)
        install.run(self)


setup(
    ...
```

( check the abovementioned tutorial for the usage of setuptools in your project )

Comment: I am not very sure about hardcoding the directory this way, because if Lambda team decides to switch the underlying container/VM, things might break?

Comment: There should be a environment variable called `LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT`. You could access it programmatically through: `import os` then `os.environ['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT']`. Use it to check the value and change programmatically the file `pip.conf` (hint: the lib *ConfigParser* handles INI files). Anyways you use pip to install packages sometimes: it is a good policy to check the environ. beforehand, even if using only an autoated task.

Comment: When I share the repository on DVCS, I'd like other programmers to be able to simply run `pip install`, without having to (1) track the dependencies in git and (2) them having to manually move the deps out into the root dir before packaging & deploying. So even if it is solved for one platform, a better solution would be to solve it across the board (via pip maybe?).

Comment: Note: if you are creating a zip containing the project-dir, lambda will take the zip content as the current project root, as per Aws's own [recommendations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html): `Zip the directory content, not the directory. The contents of the Zip file are available as the current working directory of the Lambda function.` Another way is to hook a pre-installation script to pip install with a *setup.py*.

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding what you're trying to clarify with the `zip content` statement. Would be great if you could add an example of that and the `setup.py` in your answer.

Comment: If you are having troubles with the point of creating the .zip, follow closely the [tutorial posted by AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html#with-s3-example-deployment-pkg-python). The gotcha is to zip the content of the directory *site-packages* of the virtual env (usually: $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages) where there are all dependencies. To this zip you add your script(s). The zip's own file-system will become the root of the lambda and so it get shipped with all the dependencies it needs. This is what AWS advices to do for most cases.

Comment: Okay, yes, moving my actual code into the `virtualenv`'s library path and zipping _that_ is actually a very nice idea, and I didn't think about that :-) thanks! However if there was a way to achieve what I asked in the original question (w.r.t `pip` conf), I wouldn't have to do any moving...